# Nesting columns with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 issue. When i want to nest columns, there is an offset between the column and the row. Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="parent_col" style="height: 200px;background-color: blue;">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100px;" id="included_row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Colonne</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code, "included_row" is offset from "parent_col". Here is a screen shot : http://lauragaisfc.com/example.png

Does someone have an idea? I have already seen this page ([Bootstrap 3 Nesting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027928/bootstrap-3-nesting-issue)), but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: can you show your demo in jsfiddle? or post a screen-shot.

Comment: Here is a screen shot : http://lauragaisfc.com/example.png

Comment: i don't understand your question. If you expect the Colonne having a height of 100px style them `.col-md-2{height:100px;}`. Okay now i see. The code above don't have this problem. It should be something else in your css code, see: http://bootply.com/84537

Comment: @BassJobsen : No, I just want to align blue area and red area (see the screen shot)

Comment: @BassJobsen : Thanks for your help ! It was a problem with an old link (bootstrap-responsive.css, from bootstrap 2.3) and I forgot to remove it. And great tool bootply !